# Redis is not saving anything for weeks with default config

Tags: redis

I have come across this issue on two different machines, the config file (absolutely unchanged from the default) says:

```
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
```

But no change is saved to `dump.rdb` at all, until I manually call `SAVE` from `redis-cli`. There are more than 10 changes to the DB, but much less than 10000, could that be that last option overrides previous? Why the data is kept in RAM for weeks without save?

Version is `2.8.4`

Answer (score 0):

Most probably , the redis server does not have permission to write dump.rdb file to the current directory.

```
# The filename where to dump the DB
dbfilename dump.rdb

# The working directory.
#
# The DB will be written inside this directory, with the filename specified
# above using the 'dbfilename' configuration directive.
#
# The Append Only File will also be created inside this directory.
#
# Note that you must specify a directory here, not a file name.
dir ./
```

Try changing the dir to `/tmp/` and see if the file gets written.
Then change the config to some other writable directory of your choice.

Comment: When I type `SAVE` in the client, everything is saved successfully, so, logically, it is not the permission problem.